# Issue with align/alignat and equations

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, align, amsmath, alignat

I would appreciate help with this.

I'm trying to align a couple of equations but am having some issues.
1. With this code shouldn't the \wedge be properly aligned with the >. This happens for both alignat and align.

My objective would be to align these and have equal spacing between them and the expressions on either side.

%Edit: Add clarification on output

```
   if        d > d                25
 then        M > eta              26
 with  bla bla A O(bla bla)       27
```

Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

  \begin{alignat}{5}
     \label{eq:test}
     \mathrm{iff}  \quad &&\frac{\partial L}{\partial\eta_2} \quad&>&&\quad\displaystyle\frac{\partial L}{\partial M} && \\
     \mathrm{then} \quad &&M                                 \quad&>&&\quad\sigma\eta_2  && \\
     \mathrm{with} \quad &&0 \le \eta_2 \le 1                \quad&\wedge&&\quad \mathrm{O}(\sigma) \le 1 \quad \blacksquare &&
 \end{alignat}

 \begin{align}
     \label{eq:test}
     \mathrm{iff}  \quad &&\frac{\partial L}{\partial\eta_2} \quad&>&\quad\displaystyle\frac{\partial L}{\partial M} && \\
     \mathrm{then} \quad &&M                                 \quad&>&\quad\sigma\eta_2  && \\
     \mathrm{with} \quad &&0 \le \eta_2 \le 1                \quad&\wedge&\quad \mathrm{O}(\sigma) \le 1 \quad \blacksquare &&
 \end{align}  
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.- Which alignment do you want to achieve?

Comment: "My objective would be to align these and have equal spacing between them and the expressions on either side." So pretty much get the edit on the question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether such alignments carry any meaning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\text{iff}  &\quad& \pder{L}{\eta_2}   &>\pder{L}{M}  \\
\text{then} &\quad& M                  &>\sigma\eta_2 \\
\text{with} &\quad& 0 \le \eta_2 \le 1 &\mathrel{\wedge}
   \mathrm{O}(\sigma) \le 1 \quad \blacksquare
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked, thanks! I see now there were a lot of issues with using too many alignments in my case. Set as answer. Just a question if you don't mind, isn't the number inside alignat{**#**} supposed to be, according to the documentation, the number of rl pais?

Comment: @CMichael Yes, here we have got two pairs.

Comment: My bad, was still partially thinking on my example in which I abused the alignments. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The `eqparbox` package can help. Is this what you want? (I find the spacing a little weird…)?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makebox}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\usepackage{eqparbox}

    \newcommand\eqmathbox[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle{}#2{}$}}

    \begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{5}
     \label{eq:test}
     \mathrm{iff} \quad &&\frac{\partial L}{\partial\eta_2} \quad&\eqmathbox{>}&&\quad\displaystyle\frac{\partial L}{\partial M} && \\
     \mathrm{then} \quad &&M \quad&\eqmathbox{>}&&\quad\sigma\eta_2 && \\
     \mathrm{with} \quad &&0 \le \eta_2 \le 1 \quad&\eqmathbox{\wedge} &&\quad \mathrm{O}(\sigma) \le 1 \quad \blacksquare &&
 \end{alignat}

 \begin{align}
     \label{eq:test}
     \mathrm{iff} \quad &&\frac{\partial L}{\partial\eta_2} \quad& \eqmathbox{>}&\quad\displaystyle\frac{\partial L}{\partial M} && \\
     \mathrm{then} \quad &&M \quad&\eqmathbox{>}&\quad\sigma\eta_2 && \\
     \mathrm{with} \quad &&0 \le \eta_2 \le 1 \quad&\eqmathbox{\wedge}&\quad \mathrm{O}(\sigma) \le 1 \quad \blacksquare &&
 \end{align}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, did not know such a package existed! If you don't mind, is there also any way to align **both** sets of symbols using eqmathbox?

Comment: @CMichael: Do you mean aligning the symbols in `align` and in `alignat`?

Comment: Yes, if possible, but perhaps across `alignat`s would be sufficient in my case. I'm trying with a different `alignat` one with {2} and one with {3} and, thus far, they do not appear to align.

Comment: You can group them as a unique `alignat{3}`, with one of them having one empty column. Hard to say more without  having the exact example. The way `eqparbox` works is that it uses a   tag instead of a width, so that all `\eqparbox`es sharing the same tag have the width of the widest contents.

Answer (score 1):

with align:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
 \begin{align}
     \label{eq:test}
 \mathrm{iff}  &&
        \frac{\partial L}{\partial\eta_2}\     > &\ \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial M}  &&\\
 \mathrm{then}  &&
        M\                                     > &\ \sigma\eta_2                    &&\\
 \mathrm{with}  &&0
        \le \eta_2 \le 1\                \wedge  &\ \mathrm{O}(\sigma)\le 1\quad \blacksquare &&
 \end{align}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind, could you explain the usage of the "&\" I'm finding it but haven't found an explanation on it thus far.

Comment: @CMichael, `&\ ` gives space of one letter after `&`. i used it instead of your `&\quad`.

Comment: the wider spaces to the left of the greater-than signs emphasize the fact that the wedge is `\mathbin` and not `\mathrel`.  the latter fact is the crux of the problem.

Comment: Yet it fails to produce even spacing on both sides. There's more on the right than on the left. The description of the amsmath align(at) environments suggests that the `&` precedes the binary operators to be aligned vertically. That's why I'd prefer the solution provided by egreg.